# hide and unhide a Stack View

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to hide a stack view when the keyboard is up and then unhide it again when the keyboard moves down again. The problem is that when the stack view is unhidden, the Views(I have some buttons) is out the screen?

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        self.myStackView.hidden = true
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        self.myStackView.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the Stack View's alpha to 0 so it seems invisible, but would still be there.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        self.myStackView.alpha = 0
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        self.myStackView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```